# Ревью библиотеки для работы с динамическими строками на Си

Tags: c, строки, инспекция-кода

Сегодня залил в реп первую версию библиотеки для работы с динамическими строками на Си: https://github.com/maksspace/dynamic-string

Товарищи, посмотрите это творение и выскажете свое мнение об этом. Буду очень признателен за конструктивную критику.

**dstring.h**

```
/*
 * Dyncamic strings.
 * Smagin Maksim 2015
 */

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef maksspace_dstring_h
#define maksspace_dstring_h

/* Data type dstring */
typedef struct dstring dstring_t;

/* ========== */
/*   ======   */
/*     ==     */

/* Base funcitons */
dstring_t* dstr_new(const char* init);
void dstr_delete(dstring_t* str);
dstring_t* dstr_set(dstring_t* str, const char* val);
dstring_t* dstr_truncate(dstring_t* str, size_t len);
size_t dstr_len(const dstring_t* str);
void dstr_swap(dstring_t* str1, dstring_t* str2);
dstring_t* dstr_insert(dstring_t* str, const char* val, size_t n);
dstring_t* dstr_append(dstring_t* str, const char* val);
dstring_t* dstr_prepend(dstring_t* str, const char* val);
int dstr_equal(const dstring_t* str1, const dstring_t* str2);
dstring_t* dstr_toupper(dstring_t* str);
dstring_t* dstr_tolower(dstring_t* str);
void dstr_fprint(const dstring_t* str, FILE* file);

#endif /* maksspace_dstring_h */
```

**dstring.c**

```
/*
 * Dyncamic strings. Implementation
 * Smagin Maksim 2015
 */

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "dstring.h"
#include "dstring_allocator.h"

struct dstring
{
    char* data;
    size_t length;
    size_t capacity;
};

#define DSTRING_CAPMARGIN 48
#define DSTRING_DEFAULT_CAPACITY 16

#define DSTRING_ERR_RESIZE 0
#define DSTRING_SUCC_RESIZE 1

/* Resize dstring capacity */
static int dstr_capacity_resize(dstring_t* str, size_t capacity)
{
    char* temp_data_ptr = (char*)dstr_realloc(str->data, capacity);
    if(temp_data_ptr == NULL) return DSTRING_ERR_RESIZE;
    str->data = temp_data_ptr;
    str->capacity = capacity;

    return DSTRING_SUCC_RESIZE;
}

/*
 * Base function implementation
 */

/* Create new dynamic string and init that string $init.
   Return pointer into created dynamic string, or NULL if can't allocate memory for that. */
dstring_t* dstr_new(const char* init)
{
    dstring_t* str = (dstring_t*)dstr_malloc(sizeof(dstring_t));
    if(str == NULL) return NULL;

    size_t data_capacity = DSTRING_DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
    size_t init_len = 0;
    if(init != NULL)
    {
        init_len = strlen(init);
        data_capacity += init_len;
    }

    str->data = (char*)dstr_malloc(data_capacity);
    if(str->data == NULL)
    {
        free(str);
        return NULL;
    }

    str->length = init_len;
    str->capacity = data_capacity;
    memcpy(str->data, init, init_len);

    return str;
}

/* Free memory which takes dynamic string. */
void dstr_delete(dstring_t* str)
{
    if(str != NULL)
    {
        dstr_free(str->data);
        dstr_free(str);
    }
}

/* Truncate dynamic string $str to fixed length $len from the beginning $str. */
dstring_t* dstr_truncate(dstring_t* str, size_t len)
{
    if(str != NULL && str->length > len)
    {
        if(dstr_capacity_resize(str, DSTRING_DEFAULT_CAPACITY + len))
            str->length = len;
    }
    return str;
}

/* Set value of dynamic string $str equal $val. */
dstring_t* dstr_set(dstring_t* str, const char* val)
{

    if(val == NULL)
    {
        if(dstr_capacity_resize(str, DSTRING_DEFAULT_CAPACITY))
            str->length = 0;;

    }
    else
    {
        size_t val_len = strlen(val);
        if(dstr_capacity_resize(str, DSTRING_DEFAULT_CAPACITY + val_len))
        {
            str->length = val_len;
            memcpy(str->data, val, val_len);
        }
    }
    return str;
}

/* Output dstring value into stream */
void dstr_fprint(const dstring_t* str, FILE* file)
{
    if(file == NULL || str == NULL) return;
    fwrite(str->data, 1, str->length, file);
}

/* Return length of dynamic string $str. */
size_t dstr_len(const dstring_t* str)
{
    return str->length;
}

/* Swaps values of two dynamic strings. */
void dstr_swap(dstring_t* str1, dstring_t* str2)
{
    if(str1 == NULL || str2 == NULL) return;

    char* temp_data_ptr = str1->data;
    size_t temp_length = str1->length;
    size_t temp_capacity = str1->capacity;

    str1->capacity = str2->capacity;
    str1->length = str2->length;
    str1->data = str2->data;

    str2->data = temp_data_ptr;
    str2->capacity = temp_capacity;
    str2->length = temp_length;
}

/* Append string into dsting. */
dstring_t* dstr_append(dstring_t* str, const char* val)
{
    if(str == NULL || val == NULL) return str;

    size_t val_len = strlen(val);
    if(val_len > (str->capacity - str->length))
    {
        size_t new_capacity = str->capacity + val_len + DSTRING_CAPMARGIN;
        if(!dstr_capacity_resize(str, new_capacity))
            return str;
        str->capacity = new_capacity;
    }

    memcpy(str->data + str->length, val, val_len);
    str->length += val_len;
    return str;
}

/* Prepend string into dsting. */
dstring_t* dstr_prepend(dstring_t* str, const char* val)
{
    if(str == NULL || val == NULL) return str;
    if(str->length == 0) return str = dstr_set(str, val);

    size_t val_len = strlen(val);
    if(val_len == 0) return str;

    size_t new_capacity = str->capacity + val_len;
    if(!dstr_capacity_resize(str, new_capacity))
        return str;

    str->capacity = new_capacity;

    // move the $str value on $val_len characters to rigth
    memmove(str->data + val_len, str->data, str->length);
    memcpy(str->data, val, val_len);
    str->length += val_len;
    return str;
}

/* Compare two dynamic strings and return 1 if they are equals or 0 - if don't. */
int dstr_equal(const dstring_t* str1, const dstring_t* str2)
{
    if(str1->length != str2->length) return 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < str1->length; i++)
    {
        if(str1->data[i] != str2->data[i])
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

/* Converts dynamic string characters to uppercase. */
dstring_t* dstr_toupper(dstring_t* str)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < str->length; i++)
        str->data[i] = toupper(str->data[i]);
    return str;
}


/* Converts dynamic string characters to lowercase. */
dstring_t* dstr_tolower(dstring_t* str)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < str->length; i++)
        str->data[i] = tolower(str->data[i]);
    return str;
}

/* Insert value of string $val after $n character $str. */
dstring_t* dstr_insert(dstring_t* str, const char* val, size_t n)
{
    if(val == NULL || n > str->length) return str;

    size_t val_len = strlen(val);
    if(val_len == 0) return str;

    size_t new_capacity = str->capacity + val_len;
    if(dstr_capacity_resize(str, new_capacity))
        str->capacity = new_capacity;

    // move the $str value on $val_len characters to rigth
    memmove(str->data + val_len + n, str->data + n, str->length - n);
    memcpy(str->data + n, val, val_len);
    str->length += val_len;
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Вопросы и ответы должны быть самодостаточными. Ссылки имеют свойство умирать. Так как библиотека очень маленькая, то добавил код прямо в вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Очень топорная реализация со странными оптимизациями.

1. У вас только одна перегрузка для конкатенации: dstring + char*. Нет способа эффективно слить две динамические строки.

   Следует добавить перегрузки для различных типов аргументов во все подходящие функции, чтобы всегда эффективно использовались все доступные данные. При конкатенации двух динамических строк вызов `strlen` избыточен.
2. Выделение памяти с константным запасом, а не экпоненциальным. При работе с короткими строками большой перерасход памяти, а при работе с длинными — низкая производительность.

   Традиционно память выделяют по степеням двойки.
3. Вы изобретаете множество велосипедов вместо использования проверенных временем `strncmp` и прочих.

   По возможности полагайтесь на встроенные функции везде, где возможно. Скорее всего, они гораздо лучше оптимизированы, чем ваши голые циклы по байтам.

Answer (score 0):

Очень ограниченный API непонятного назначения.

Вы реализуете контейнер в который можно добавлять только полные "сишные строки" *без какого-либо доступа к его содержимому* (за исключением тотальной смены регистра символов), кроме выгрузки в файл.

О недостатке с распределением памяти Вам уже написал в своем ответе @Discord, хотя, возможно мы просто не видим реального механизма, скрытого  в функциях `dstr_malloc()/dstr_realloc()`.

Мне кажется, что улучшить ситуацию можно предоставив доступ к хранимым данным (хотя, может быть Вы как раз и хотели это сделать (магическое слово инкапсуляция)).

Если решитесь, то  Вам нужно будет хранить вместе с содержимым строки и завершающий ее 0. А простейший способ предоставления этого доступа -- тривиально не прятать внутреннее представление структуры `struct dstring`.

Тогда пользователь может использовать все стандартные строковые strcmp/stcrhr/strspn/... и т.д.

Также, вместо 3-х функций `dstr_insert, dstr_append, dstr_prepend` достаточно одной -- модифицированной
`dstring_t *dstr_insert(dstring_t *dstr, size_t destination_pos, const char *src_str, size_t length)`,
которая вставляет length (или менее) байт в позицию `destination_pos` динамической строки, сдвигая ее остаток вправо. Специфические способы ее использования -- вставка nil-terminated, вставка в начало (prepend), добавление в конец (append) можно оформить в виде макросов.

Заодно, я бы добавил функцию
`dstring_t *dstr_remove(dstring_t *dstr, size_t from_pos, size_t length)`
 для удаления length байт с указанной позиции.

Ну, и на мой вкус, краткие комментарии как работают функции вместе с описанием их прототипов в .h не были бы лишними.